# monotouch no longer combines xib with .cs and .designer.cs files

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Before upgrading to version Mono 2.10.9, XCode 4.2 and Monotouch 5.2.11 I used to see just the myfile.xib file and 'underneath' (in expanded mode) I would see the corresponding myfile.xib.cs and myfile.xib.designer.cs files.

Now I see the myfile.xib on its own and a separate myfile.cs with underneath it myfile.designer.cs.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how to go back to what it was before? (ie just a single xib with underneath it the cs and designer files)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. There are no longer foo.xib.designer.cs files, because xibs from Xcode 4 do not define classes, so classes cannot be generated from them. Instead, the *classes* have designer parts, and the designer modifies the designer parts of the classes directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is how things are since MonoDevelop 2.6. Some stuff changed when the stand-alone Interface Builder "died" and this is one of them.

From what I understand, you cannot go back to that, unless you don't mind having outdated stuff.

**EDIT:**
I think it is better this way because I used to accidentally open the XIB files quite often, instead of the source files I wanted to with the old versions.